# Unlocking Bootloader

Tags: boot, bootloader, sony-xperia-p

Recently I've unlocked my sony xperia p boot loader. I am sure that it is unlocked. But is there any option to find out that is it unlocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter `*#*#7378423#*#*` to access the service menu.

Tap Service info > Configuration

If unlocked, it says, `Bootloader unlock done` under `Rooting Status`